# Get files using ListFile but filtering by its name that has a date inside it

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

please help!

I have files whose name is formed by a date in the format "yymmdd", for example:

TRB_ASE_D190125.txt

TRB_TIT_D190125.txt

I need to get only the files whose names match the current date. For example, if the date was "190125", the 2 subsequent files would match that criterion.

I am using the ListFile processor to get the files and put this regular expression using the "now" function in the File Filter, but it does not work:

^TRB_[A-Z]+_D${now():format('yymmdd')}.TXT

Thanks in advance!

Comment: according to [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFile/index.html) the File Filter parameter does not support expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

ListFile -> RouteOnAttribute -> FetchFile

The RouteOnAttribute processor will have the filter pattern, in this case it's possible to use Expression Language, so it's going to route to the FetchFile only the desired files.